# Magento2.3 and Magmi

Tags: magmi, magento2.3, import-products

I'm working on one module. module does read CSV file from var/import and making a call to Magmi to import.

> RunQuickImport.php

```
namespace Test\Import\Controller\Adminhtml\Customimport;
class RunQuickImport extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
public function execute()
    {
    $csv_data =readcsv file ;
    foreach($csv_data as $row){
       $dp = Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance("productimport");
       $dp->beginImportSession("default", "xcreate");
       $item = "product field array";
       $run = $dp->ingest($item);
       $dp->endImportSession();
         }
     }
}
```

Question is How to include Magmi file in controller ?

I had tried using following.

```
require_once '/public_html/magmi/inc/magmi_defs.php';
require_once '/public_html/magmi/integration/inc/magmi_datapump.php';
```

but not working

Comment: Did you have any solution?

Comment: yes you can add same code in top of  module's registration.php file.

Answer (score 1):

> You can include magmi file in your controller like Below:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../../../../magmi/inc/magmi_defs.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../../../../magmi/integration/inc/magmi_datapump.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

-> If Your magmi folder on magentoRoot/pub then

**registration.php**

```
<?php
require_once BP . "/pub/magmi/plugins/inc/magmi_datasource.php";
require_once BP . "/pub/magmi/integration/inc/productimport_datapump.php";

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendoreName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

-> If your magmi folder On Magento Root Then

**registration.php**

```
<?php
require_once BP . "/magmi/plugins/inc/magmi_datasource.php";
require_once BP . "/magmi/integration/inc/productimport_datapump.php";

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendoreName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

> Try This Code

```
public function execute()
{
    $csv_data =readcsv file ;
    foreach($csv_data as $row){
        $configProduct = new \Magmi_ProductImport_DataPump();
        $item = "product field array"; = "product field array";;
        $configProduct->beginImportSession("default", "xcreate");// Mode: xcreate, create, update
        $run = $configProduct->ingest($item);
        $configProduct->endImportSession();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Code use in top of module's registration.php file.

```
require_once BP . "/magmi/plugins/inc/magmi_datasource.php";
require_once BP . "/magmi/integration/inc/productimport_datapump.php";
```

In Class file.

```
 $dp = new \Magmi_ProductImport_DataPump();
 $dp->beginImportSession("default", 'magmi mode');
```